# Hue File Browser not working

Tags: hadoop, hue

i have installed hue and the file browser in hue is not working and is throwing a "Server Error (500)"

data from error.log

```
webhdfs      ERROR    Failed to determine superuser of WebHdfs at http://namenode:50070/webhdfs/v1: SecurityException: Failed to obtain user group information: org.apache.hadoop.security.authorize.AuthorizationException: User: hue is not allowed to impersonate hue (error 401)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hduser/huef/hue/desktop/libs/hadoop/src/hadoop/fs/webhdfs.py", line 108, in superuser
    sb = self.stats('/')
  File "/home/hduser/huef/hue/desktop/libs/hadoop/src/hadoop/fs/webhdfs.py", line 188, in stats
    res = self._stats(path)
  File "/home/hduser/huef/hue/desktop/libs/hadoop/src/hadoop/fs/webhdfs.py", line 182, in _stats
    raise ex
```

Note :  i have added the following to core-site.xml and i have enabled webhdfs

```
 <property>
                <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hue.hosts</name>
                <value>*</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hue.groups</name>
                <value>*</value>
        </property>
```

Error when i try to access hdfs file location through oozie in hue

```
An error occurred: SecurityException: Failed to obtain user group information: org.apache.hadoop.security.authorize.AuthorizationException: User: hue is not allowed to impersonate hduser (error 401)
```

Answer (score 11):

core-site.xml

```
 <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hue.hosts</name>
      <value>*</value>
 </property>
 <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hue.groups</name>
      <value>*</value>
 </property>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
<property>
     <name>dfs.webhdfs.enabled</name>
     <value>true</value>
</property>
```

Comment: which path? on master node?

Comment: Hadoop configuration files are stored on each hadoop node in directory /etc/hadoop/conf. You can use cluster manager software (e.g. Ambari) to manage configurations and edit them only once.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify hduser as the proxy user:

```
 <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hduser.hosts</name>
      <value>*</value>
 </property>
 <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hduser.groups</name>
      <value>*</value>
 </property>
```

BTW: why are you not running Hue as 'hue'?

Comment: tried changing core-site.xml as you said, it still gives me the same error. Tried to run Hue as 'hue' and not as hduser.  Still getting the same error. Have edited question with the new error log.

Comment: Did you restart the NameNode?

Comment: Yes I did stop-dfs.sh, stop-mapred.sh and then start-dfs.sh, start-mapred.sh. That will be sufficient right?

Comment: i didnt create a separate user for 'hue'. Installed it using an existing user 'hduser'. That is why i was running hue as 'hduser'. And one more thing, when i restart my cluster the secondarynamenode is not getting stopped. can that be a reason?

Comment: can you identify the issue?

Comment: If you manage your stack with Ambari then you need to add these properties through the GUI, otherwise the manually edited files will be overwritten when the services are restarted via the GUI.

Answer (score 2):

What user are you logged as?

I had same issue, my solution was to create a HUE user called "hdfs" and added "hue" Linux user in "hadoop" and "hdfs" linux users groups.

So now I am logged in as "hdfs" user in HUE web UI.

Answer (score 0):

You may see it says `Failed to obtain user group information`.

According to [Hadoop docs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsPermissionsGuide.html#Group_Mapping), the group info is gathered by invoking shell command (on *nix system) `groups $USERNAME`. Therefore, the matching user **MUST EXIST** as a Linux user in **HDFS Namenode**, where authentication process occurs.

So the solution is simple as,

`useradd hue -g root`

On the **Namenode**.

I'm deploying hdfs in a docker container, so I use group `root`. The value is the same as the user running the Namenode process (who is definitely the superuser).