# Unable to access Hadoop services from Hue after Hadoop installation

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, hdfs, hue

I installed Hadoop on a Ubuntu VM. I configured HDFS and I am able to access it from the terminal. I tried several commands and it works well.

Then, I wanted to install Hue. I cloned the project and installed it. But it seems to have a lot of errors. This is the list if errors that I get ( on top right corner ) when I launch it:

> Cannot access: /. The HDFS REST service is not available.
>
> Could not connect to localhost:10000
>
> Could not connect to localhost:10000 (code THRIFTTRANSPORT):
>   TTransportException('Could not connect to localhost:10000',)

When  I try to access the file browser I get this error:

Cannot access: /user/hadoop. The HDFS REST service is not available.

> HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=50070): Max retries exceeded
>   with url:
>   /webhdfs/v1/user/hadoop?op=GETFILESTATUS&user.name=hue&doas=hadoop
>   (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection:
>   [Errno 111] Connection refused',))

I read that I need to change the **/opt/hue/desktop/conf.disthue.ini** file and decomment this line:

```
    # Use WebHdfs/HttpFs as the communication mechanism.
      # Domain should be the NameNode or HttpFs host.
      # Default port is 14000 for HttpFs.
webhdfs_url=http://localhost:50070/webhdfs/v1

      # Change this if your HDFS cluster is Kerberos-secured
      ## security_enabled=false
```

But I still have the same problem. I tried multiple solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614940/hue-file-browser-not-working) But nothing works. Ideas? Thank you

I also installed hive which is also unaccessible from hue but works from the terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Hadoop 3 hdfs port number changed from 50070 to 9870. So I only had to apply the same changes in *hue.init* file. i.e: if you are working with Hadoop 3.*.* and have the same problem, just replace:

```
webhdfs_url=localhost:50070/webhdfs/v1
```

with

```
webhdfs_url=localhost:9870/webhdfs/v1
```